# What is the minimum hard drive space needed to develop for Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain

I'm looking into buying a Chromebook and running Crouton or Chrubuntu however the Chromebook I want only has 32GB of hard drive space. Is this sufficient to develop with or will the blockchain take up too much space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just about possible to develop without running a full production network node locally, in which case you just need to be able to run a local private network, and maybe a testnet node, and 32GB will be fine.

However, it's useful to be able to run a full production node. My current `geth --fast` node is about 15GB, and that grows after the initial sync and you have to delete the chain database and resync every now and again. The 15GB will also increase over time, so it probably won't work for long.

So get more than 32GB if practical.

Comment: I'm assuming running off an SD card or USB would not be ideal?

Comment: Oh, that should work too.

Comment: I did observed writing blockchain into SD card or USB takes longer time.@Alexr1239